# Change the style of an input only when it is followed by a span

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I target the `<input>` only when there is `<span>` after it?

```
<fieldset>
   <p>Normal Input</p>
   <div>
     <input name="">
     <span><i class="icon-cart"></i></span>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

`input + span {}` would only work if the `<span>` was before the `<input>` but in this case it is after the `<input>` - Is there a way to target it without using JavaScript or adding classes to the parent container?

[image]

As you can see in the image below, I just want to change the input border-radius so it merge with the span icon us like on all the other scenarios.

Comment: How do you want to target it? to do what to it?

Comment: I just want to change its border-radius

Comment: Updated my answer Leo

Comment: change the order of the markup, then float right the span and float left the input

Comment: If there is no i element here unlike in your previous question, you could try `input:only-child`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a class say, you could use JQuery like this:

```
$('span').prev('input').addClass('test');
```

Or to add a border-radius:

```
$('span').prev('input').css('border-radius','3px');
```

Comment: Can I do that without using JavaScript please?

Comment: Not unless you can add classes to the HTML - not as far as I know anyway

Comment: Thank you, there is a way but it is really complex CSS - I am nearly there now. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Ok cool, can you post your answer when you figure it out? Would be interested in seeing that